# Python: call operator from a toggle?

Tags: python

Is there a way to call an operator when a toggle is pressed? For example, suppose the users presses the X Symmetry toggle when in Sculpt mode. Is there a way to call an operator when this happens? Or do I need to use a modal operator and check every time if the toggle has changed?

Comment: do you want an operation that works when the use_symmetry changes, or do you want to change blender's behaviour depending on which symmetry is set?

Comment: Well, in the second case I guess I must use a modal operator anyway, so the first one...

Comment: I would create an operator to replace the current ui operator... It's far better than keeping a modal running constantly.